# how to show $f(iz) = if(z)$ under the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a $f$ isomorphism that map unit square to the unit circle in the complex plane, and also $f(0) = 0$

the question is how to prove that $f(iz)$ = $if(z)$ for every $z \in$ unit square.

I tried showing that $Arg(f(iz)) = Arg(if(z))$. using the fact the angles between path remain the same and using the fact that the points $1,-1,i,-i$ must map to points *on* the circle . but I got lost. anyway I still had the problem of showing the norm are the same

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming, by "unit square" you mean the square $[{-1},1]^2\subset{\mathbb C}$.)

A hint:
Consider the function $g(z):=f^{-1}\bigl(f(iz)\bigr)$

Comment: Another hint: Use the first hint, together with the uniqueness part of the Riemann mapping theorem...

Comment: not sure I got it. but if I say that $g(z) = f(iz)$ and $h(z) = if(z)$ . both iso. from unit square to unit cicle , and $g(0)=h(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=h'(0)=i*f'(0)$ is that enough ? I feel that I'm missing something here...